# Writing data to bluetooth

Tags: java, android, bluetooth

In my project I have two classes in the other files.

The second class is the class from documentation AndroidStudio about sending data.
https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth.html

The first class is my mainactivity.

So, I have this code fragment:

```
     public class MyBluetoothService {
//some code
public class ConnectedThread extends Thread {
//some code
 public void write(byte[] bytes) {//some code
}
}
}
```

And in the first class I try to use methods: write() just like God said so:

```
    MyBluetoothService.ConnectedThread send= new MyBluetoothService.ConnectedThread();
send.write(my_data);
```

But I have this error:

```
Error:(74, 55) error: an enclosing instance that contains MyBluetoothService.ConnectedThread is required
```

Why? Where is the problem? What should I do to fix this?

Comment: seems to me that something needs to be extended or implemented...

Comment: @Taslim I know but I don't what I need